# Calling parent View Controller function from a subview

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, subview

I have a parent ViewController with two subview controllers.

When I load the parent view controller it will display two of the subviews. I can also swipe left or right to slide subviews. I now have a requirement to add a button on subviews. On clicking the button it should slide automatically to next subview.

This is what i'm planning -  place a button on subview viewcontroller. Hitting the button will call a function in parent viewcontroller that is responsible for sliding. right now i'm unable to call parent viewcontroller's function. I need the current instance of parent view controller.
Can someone please help?

on the picture, grey is subview viewcontroller 1
green is is subview viewcontroller 2. 
clicking on button of viewcontroller1 should slide to viewcontroller 2

[Please click here for screen print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgeEv.png)

Comment: what are  you  trying? share the code please . there have any error ? if so what is that ?

Comment: @NazmulHasan - Three ViewControllers - VC1, VC2 and VC3.
 VC1 is the parent and VC2, VC3 are subviews.
VC1 displays both VC2 and VC3 as card style that can be swiped left or right ( This part is working).
I would like to have a button on VC2 so that on click, it slides to VC3 automatically

Comment: may be ! you can be done by  protocol

Comment: @NazmulHasan - I'm a newbie.. Any more details you can provide? I have added a screen print to the question if you wanna take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions I can think of off the top of my head:

1. Make your button a subview of the parent view controller; this will obviously not work if you want your button to be a subview of one of the child view controller views.
2. To expand on @NazmulHasan's suggestion, you could implement a custom protocol for your child view controllers. To take child view controller 1 as an example, you simply need to declare a delegate protocol for that class. This tells the compiler which functions the delegate of the view controller has to implement to satisfy the protocol. So you'd do something like this:

```
    protocol childViewControllerOneDelegate {
        func buttonWasPressed(sender: UIButton) -> Void
    }
```

You also need to add a property to your child view controller as follows:

```
var myDelegate : childViewControllerOneDelegate!
```

It's an implicitly unwrapped optional because you cannot set the delegate when the class is initialized; you set it as I'm going to outline below.

At the very top of your parent view controller class declaration, you then declare that the view controller complies with this protocol:

```
class parentViewController : UIViewController, childViewControllerOneDelegate ... Etc, etc {
```

When you initialize childViewControllerOne from the parent view controller, you can then add a line straight afterwards that says:

```
myChildViewControllerOne.delegate = self
```

Finally, going back to your button and the child view controller, you simply add an action to it that calls the following:

```
self.myDelegate.buttonWasPressed(self.button)
```

This will trigger the method in the parent view controller and you can do whatever you need to do.

Hope that helps. As always with these answers, I'm trying to compress a lot of info into a small space, so drop me a line if you have any questions. All best!

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross referencing. You'll have to pass a weak reference of the parent viewController to the child after the initialization.